How to replace values on ETL process?
I have a simple ETL from CSV to SQL Table.
Here is the current workflow (see picture attached)

first object is a Flat file source
then a lookup
lookup match will update existing record (OLE DB Command - Execute stored procedure)
lookup no match will insert into SQL table (OLE DB Destination)


Here is the problematic csv data



ID
Name
Number




1
Jone
345


2
Jane
222


3
Phil
?



Data type for Number is Integer. So obviously Phil is throwing an error
Now I want to always replace "?" with zero . I have a plan in my head, but I don't know how to execute it. My plan is to load the CSV into a Temp table.And just run a Replace command, But I don't know where to start.
select Replace(Number, '?', '0') "Number" from Temp_Table1

How do I do that?
also open for other suggestion. But I need to be able to automate the clean up of "?"

Create a permanent staging table in your database.
Then in your control flow

Truncate the staging table in an Execute SQL Task
Load the CSV file into the staging table with a Data Flow Task
Transform and MERGE the staging table into the target table with another Execute SQL Task.  As a best practice, build a stored procedure to encapsulate this logic.


where does the lookup fit into this?
I have a lookup that will do Update if it's existing, or insert if no match

Don't use lookup.  Keep your Data Flows simple and move the logic to TSQL.  This is a general best practice when loading SQL Server with SSIS.  Putting logic in a Dataflow is  a pain to implement, and slow at runtime.

Ahhh I see , I like this. Use Execute SQL task to perform the same operation
